# Where to place plt.plot (rr,xlogistic) in the program? I'm new to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> import numpy as np
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def logistic (n,r,initialTerm) :

```
xlogistic = np.zeros((n,1))
ylogistic = np.zeros((n,1)) 
rr = r * np.ones((n,1))
    
ylogistic[0] = initialTerm
for i in range(1,n,1):
    ylogistic[i] = r*ylogistic[i-1]*(1-ylogistic[i-1])
    #print(ylogistic[i]) 

xlogistic[0] = ylogistic[100]
for i in range(1,n,1):
    xlogistic[i] = r*xlogistic[i-1]*(1-xlogistic[i-1])
    #print(xlogistic[i])
    
plt.plot(rr,xlogistic)

return (xlogistic[i])
```

"""
Testing the Functions
"""
theLogisticMap = logistic(1000,3.9,0.5)

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not clear, I'm assuming you are asking how to show the graph.
after plotting using `plt.plot` and performing other graph related commands, **you can use `plt.show()` to show the plot at the line of code you want it to be shown.**

Also, you should never loop within numpy indices, it takes a long time,
try your code using a large number that would take time to process
then modify it by converting the values to a normal python list :

```
xlogistic = np.zeros((n,1))
ylogistic = np.zeros((n,1)) 
rr = r * np.ones((n,1))

xlogistic = list(xlogistic)
ylogistic = list(ylogistic)
rr = list(rr)
```

you'll find it way faster.

=============================

since you are new to python, here are some commands you can make use of before showing the graph:

```
plt.plot(x, y, ’r--’)
```

third argument for colour (b,w,g,....) and/or style (--, -, ..). you can use one or both.

you can also plot two functions on the same graph. with or without styling

```
plt.plot(rr,xlogistic,’r’, x , y, ’--’)
```

to mark a specific point or points (same logic as plotting two functions) just plot a specific point... preferably with a good style for a point like *, unlike --

```
plt.plot(x[0], y[0], ’ro’, x[-1], y[-1], ’r*’)
```

some examples to finish off your graphs:

```
plt.xlabel('t (s)')
plt.ylabel('y (m)')
plt.legend(['Line1'])         #one legend
plt.legend([’t**2’, ’e**t’]) #multiple legends
plt.grid('on')
plt.axis([x1, x2, y1, y2])   # axes limits
plt.title(’Title’)
```

Comment: Hi mak, I am confuse. You meant to change 

xlogistic = np.zeros((n,1))
ylogistic = np.zeros((n,1)) 
rr = r * np.ones((n,1))

with

xlogistic = list(xlogistic)
ylogistic = list(ylogistic)
rr = list(rr)?

Comment: I'm talking about the part in which you made xlogistic and ylogistic using numpy, then you looped inside it using for loop. It is not efficient and will take a long time for larger sample of data. I gave you an example of using python lists instead of numpy arrays to do it. converting from the array to lists are not recommended since you can create lists from the beginning using this code for x and y logistc: [[0]*1]*n... rr can be left as numpy array since you are not looping inside it.